# How to Create Autocorrelation Function without any buit-in functions like xcorr

Tags: matlab, correlation

I want to auto-correlate a random noise vector with out any built-in MATLAB functions.

My auto correlation equation that is given is:

```
Rxx[L] = ∑ from n = 1 to N-1 [x(n)*x(n+L)]

L = [0:200]
```

I have written the code below but the `plot` `Rxx` vs `L` `plot` is not what I am expecting. 
I am expecting my plot to start at some maximum at `L = 0` or `L = 1` since MATLAB starts its index at 1. Then exponentially decrease and saturates at a min of zero.

---

```
clc
clear all

randn('seed',2496132);
n = randn(1,1024);

upperbound = numel(n)-1;

for L = 1:200

    for j = 1 : upperbound

            n1(j) = n(j)+L;
            Rxx(j) = (n(j)*n1(j));             

    end

    Rxx_sum(L) = sum(Rxx);
    Rxx = 0;

end

plot([1:200], Rxx_sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error in inner loop: you need to use `n1(j) = n(j+L);` instead `n1(j) = n(j)+L;`. E.g. you need add `L` to index instead value.

Second error is following: if you want to use `upperbound = numel(n)-1` than you should use L equal to 0 or 1 only. E.g. you outer loop will be

```
for L = 0:1
   ...
   Rxx_sum(L+1) = sum(Rxx);
   ...
```

Instead of this you can also correct upperbound value:

```
upperbound = numel(n) - maxL;
```

There `maxL` is maximal value of L that will used in next loop.

One more tip: it is possible to increase calculation speed if you replace inner loop with scalar product, e.g.

```
for L = 1:200
    Rxx_sum(L) = n(1:upperbound) * n(1+L:upperbound+L)';    
end
```

Comment: This was not exactly what I was looking for but it help to guide me on the right path. Thanks a lot Danil

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing my script with the help of the above code.

> clc
>
> clear all
>
> randn('seed',2496132);
>
> z = randn(1,1024);
>
> n = [z zeros(1,200)];
>
> upperbound = numel(z)-1;
>
> for L = 0:200

```
for j = 1 : upperbound

    Rxx(j) = (n(j)*n(j+L));             

>end

Rxx_sum(L+1) = sum(Rxx);
Rxx = 0;
```

> end
>
> plot([0:200],Rxx_sum)